# std::string replace between start and end

Tags: c++, replace, substring

I have been trying to use replace of std::string but have been unable to do so successfully.

I have a large string in which i want to do some replacement.
I know the start and end of the substring which needs to be replaced with a new one.

```
static void replaceString(string &input, const string &startString, const string &endString, const string &replacement)
{
    size_t indexStart, indexEnd;

    indexStart = input.find(startString);
    indexEnd = input.find(endString);
    if (indexStart != xml.npos) {
        input.replace(indexStart, indexEnd-indexStart, replacement);
    }
}
```

At the end of this the input remains unchanged.

What am i doing wrong here?

Regards

Comment: what is xml in line if(indexStrat != xml.npos) ?

Comment: What input to the function do you have? And what if the `endString` can't be found?

Comment: xml was a typo. it's input.

Comment: Will place a check for endString also.

Comment: @chingupt what is your input, expected output and observed output ?

Comment: lets say my input is "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z", and i want to replace everything between d and q with chingupt.

Comment: Are you certain the value of `startString` is in `input`?

Comment: yes. find returns me an indexStart value and so does the indexEnd.

Comment: As long as `xml` is changed to `input`, this function works OK for me.  Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger?

Comment: Yes. It works well with a sample program. But in actual code, i have a xml read into a string . In this xml string, i am trying to replace data between two tags, opening and closing ones. Just wont replace. Not sure why :(

Comment: Why don't you put some `cerr << "indexStart " << indexStart << ", indexEnd " << indexEnd << '\n'` output trace in, and check xml.npos == `std::string::npos`?

Comment: @Tony, i debugged the program and checked the indexStart and indexEnd values. They are populated properly.

Comment: Well, then I suggest printing out the value of input inside the `if` clause, immediately after `replace`, then working back from there.  You're not showing us enough to help you.  For example, it could be that your caller is providing a copy of the xml string so you're still not operating on the value you expect, or any of dozens of other trivial mistakes.

Comment: @Tony. It was a copy i was working on. :(

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, two checks are missing:

1. If `endString` is not found,
2. If `endString` is found *before* `startString`, in this case, your substraction to compute the second parameter of `replace()` will result in a negative length which will overflow.

Also, you might want to return a boolean to check whether there was a match or not.

Try something like this instead:

```
static bool replaceString(string &input, const string &startString, const string &endString, const string &replacement)
{
    size_t indexStart, indexEnd;
    indexStart = input.find(startString);
    if (indexStart == input.npos) {
        return false;
    }
    indexEnd = input.find(endString, indexStart); // Note the offset to start searching
                                                  // after the start index
    if (indexEnd == input.npos) {
        return false;
    }
    input.replace(indexStart, indexEnd-indexStart, replacement);
    return true;
}
```

Test program:

```
int main (int, char**)
{
    string s ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    string start ("gh");
    string end ("pq");
    string replace ("GHIJKLMNO");
    bool ok = replaceString(s, start, end, replace);

    std::cout << "1. found? " << ok << ", result: " << s << std::endl;

    start = "pq";
    end = "de";
    ok = replaceString(s, start, end, replace);

    std::cout << "2. found? " << ok << ", result: " << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1. found? true, result: abcdefGHIJKLMNOpqrstuvwxyz
2. found? false, result: abcdefGHIJKLMNOpqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Julien-L's but I think you also need to advance `indexStart` so the replacement doesn't overwrite any of the found `startString`.

```
static void replaceString(std::string &input, const std::string &startString, const std::string &endString, const std::string &replacement)
{
    size_t indexStart = input.find(startString);
    if (indexStart == input.npos) return;
    indexStart += startString.size();

    size_t indexEnd = input.find(endString, indexStart);
    if (indexEnd == input.npos) return;

    input.replace(indexStart, indexEnd - indexStart, replacement);
}
```